# How do you repackage a deb package for an older OS?

Tags: debian, dpkg, packaging, deb

I know how to extract a package, make some minor changes, and repackage it. I wanted to know if there was anything special you'd have to do if you were to repackage a deb package so it was compatible with an older OS version.

For example, I want to upgrade xyz package on Ubuntu 12 but xyz package is only available on Ubuntu 14. Can I just modify the control file to change Utopic Unicorn to Precise Pangolin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get unmet dependencies if you want to take package from newer system and install on older one. You can check dependencies in the control file in `Depends:` section.  You can try to resolve dependencies by upgrading them, but by doing so you can break other applications which depend on old versions. If you'll manage to get them, you can just rebuild package or try to install this package from source.

Answer (score 1):

If it has compiled code in the package, you need to rebuild it in most cases.

Short summary on how to do that:

To do that, download the *source* package on Ubuntu 14.04 or 14.10 (whichever you meant by "Ubuntu 14") with `apt-get source -d packagename` and copy the downloaded files, one `.dsc` and usually one `.debian.tar.xz` or `.debian.tar.gz` (sometimes still a `.diff.gz`) and usually one `.orig.tar.gz` onto the machine with the older  Ubuntu release (I assume Ubuntu 12.04 since 12.10 is no more supported).

There, unpack the source package with `dpkg-source -x file.dsc` (as the following tools from the `dpkg-dev` package) on the copied `.dsc` file and change to the created directory.

Then check if you have all build dependencies installed with `dpkg-checkbuilddeps`, install the missing ones if necessary.

Optionally run `dch --bpo` to add a proper changelog entry and version number depending on how proper the backport should be.

Then run `dpkg-buildpackage -b` to rebuild the package.